# Python one line if else with function

Tags: python

```
def test(x):
  print("in test")
  if x >0:
    return 1
  else:
    None
def whennegative():
  return 6
myval =test(3) if test(3) else whennegative()
```

Is there anyway do this one-line if-else without execute test twice? thanks

Comment: `test(3) or whennegative()`

Comment: The definition of `test` itself is odd. Are you using `1` and `None` as proxies for `True` and `False`, in which case why not simply `return x > 0`?

Comment: @chepner I just want to know the syntax

Answer (score 2):

What you're writing can be summarized as "Do `test(3)` if it works, and if it doesn't, then here's a fallback". Put another way, that can be summarized as "Do `test(3)`, or else do the fallback".

```
myval = test(3) or whennegative()
```

If `test(3)` is truthy, it'll short circuit out. Otherwise, it'll evaluate `whennegative()`.

There are people who will argue that this is too short and clever, and it can certainly be overused (if you ever see `a = (b and c) or d` then you've gone too far). But a single `or` in assignment to mean "here's a fallback" or a single `and` to mean "here's a point of failure" is pretty well understood by folks and is, indeed, more concise than the ternary alternative.